# Synchronous code with functions

Tags: javascript, promise, generator

The following functions allow synchronous blocks of code to be created with a sleep function, and without blocking.

```
function synchronous(generator)
{
   var _generator = generator();
   function done()
   {
      var result = _generator.next().value;
      if (result instanceof Promise)
         result.then(done);
   }
   done();
}

function sleep(ms)
{ 
   return new Promise(function(res, rej) { setTimeout(res, ms); });
}


// Runs without blocking, as you expect
synchronous(function* ()
{
   console.log('a');
   yield sleep(2000);
   console.log('b');
});
```

The following code however, will call functions `c()` and `d()` at the same time, instead of waiting for `c()` to finish before calling `d()`.

```
synchronous(function* ()
{
   Log('a');
   yield sleep(2000);
   Log('b');
   yield sleep(2000);

   synchronous(c);
   synchronous(d);

   function* c()
   {
      Log('c');
      yield sleep(2000);
      Log('d');
      yield sleep(2000);
   }

   function* d()
   {
      Log('e');
      yield sleep(2000);
      Log('f');
      yield sleep(2000);
   }
});
```

`Prints a b c e d f`

How can I resolve this and have `d()` start after `c()` finishes, without setting up a far more complex system of promises?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Quick solution

First of all, you can't make an asynchronous function synchronous. Asynchronity is *poisonous*, meaning all code calling asynchronous code and expecting to run sequentially has to be asynchronous itself. In your case the outer function is already asynchronous, so you can make it work by using `yield*`:

```
synchronous(function* ()
{
   Log('a');
   yield sleep(2000);
   Log('b');
   yield sleep(2000);

   yield* c();
   yield* d();

   function* c()
   {
      Log('c');
      yield sleep(2000);
      Log('d');
      yield sleep(2000);
   }

   function* d()
   {
      Log('e');
      yield sleep(2000);
      Log('f');
      yield sleep(2000);
   }
});
```

#### Good solution

Your `synchronous` function can be replaced by `babelHelpers.asyncToGenerator`:

```
function asyncToGenerator(fn) {
  return function () {
    var gen = fn.apply(this, arguments);
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      function step(key, arg) {
        try {
          var info = gen[key](arg);
          var value = info.value;
        } catch (error) {
          reject(error);
          return;
        }
        if (info.done) {
          resolve(value);
        } else {
          Promise.resolve(value).then(function (value) {
            step("next", value);
          }, function (err) {
            step("throw", err);
          });
        }
      }
      step("next");
    });
  };
}
```

This function is used to wrap a function at definition (and not at invocation), like this:

```
var a = asyncToGenerator(function*() {
    yield sleep(100);
});
var b = asyncToGenerator(function*() {
    var c = asyncToGenerator(function*() {
        yield sleep(300);
    });
    var d = asyncToGenerator(function*() {
        yield sleep(300);
    });

    yield a();
    yield sleep(200);
    yield c();
    yield d();
});

b(); // start the whole process with b
```

Answer (score 2):

`synchronous` will suspend its own execution, but *not* that of its parent stack frame. That's what separates generators from generalized coroutines. If you want to suspend execution of the outer function mid-block, it must itself be a generator and yield to its own parent stack frame. There's no escape hatch that will allow you to defer to the event loop and resume the same code block.

You can only pause execution with `yield`, and you can only `yield` from within a generator (or `async`/`await`, but same overall deal there).

You might check [this article](http://calculist.org/blog/2011/12/14/why-coroutines-wont-work-on-the-web/) for more info.

Comment: So in my case, I either don't use functions, or I call d() from within c()

Comment: @Edge Nah, you can get the order you want, you just need to make your `synchronous` helper itself a generator, so that you can nest it. Making it not so synchronous. You may want to just use https://github.com/tj/co at that point though